# FollowSymLinks error "Not allowed here"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal, centos, webmin

I've been searching for 4 hours already but I can't seem to find a solution to our problem.

**The problem we've encountered**
We have a *CentOS Linux 6.4* server, running *Virtualmin 3.99.gpl*. We have a Drupal website which we would like to move to this server, and as it's a multidomain site, we will have to use `FollowSymLinks`. This has (as I was told) been disabled as some security flaws were discovered addressing this directive. Since then you would have to use `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`. Now, Drupal has a lot of `.htaccess` files hidden deep in the roots of this system, and as I'm not sure how this new method will be supported, I wanted to ask some experts their opinion to the solution my colleague proposed.

**The Proposed solution**
My colleague told me that it would probably work if I'd wrote a simple shell script to edit all the .htaccess files in the root folder of the domain, which would replace all the `FollowSymlinks` with the `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`. As I'm not sure if this would fix this problem, I would like to ask your opinion on this.

**What we've tried**
We've tried to fix the configuration file from Apache to allow FollowSymLinks, but this did not work. Also we tried changing the global configuration in Webmin, but webmin ignored these edits (a fix for this would be great!). Deleting the line of the .htaccess in the root folder, fixes the problem, but this is not the solution we want to use.

Any other solutions, fixes or workarounds?

Comment: Just for clarity, do you mean a "multisite" or is your CentOS running apache virtual hosting? (for multiple domain support) There's exhaustive documentation for multisite setup [here](http://drupal.org/node/43816) Having setup a drupal 6 MS, I haven't had to perform anything peculiar with apache symlink configuration.

Comment: It's a multisite setup, runned by setting domainpointers to that one directory.

Comment: OK, then the file I linked to will set you up. I've never had to customize the htaccess files for the child sites, though this [one](http://drupal.org/node/138889) should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to come back at this, the proposed solution 'just works' in my case.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the description inside .htaccess file in the public directory of the Laravel(8) application, it is saying that:

```
# (3) If your web host doesn't allow the `FollowSymlinks` option,
#     you need to comment it out or remove it, and then uncomment
#     the `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` line (4), but be aware
#     of the performance impact.
```

So I just commented out #2 and uncommented #3 and that's it!

**Before:**

```
# (2)
Options +FollowSymlinks

# (3)
# Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

**After:**

```
# (2)
# Options +FollowSymlinks

# (3)
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```